# Dynamic Search Field in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, model-view-controller, rubygems

I want to build a search field that give suggestions based on what the user is typing. Like the wikipedia search bar.

It should only query for the title names (not implementing any complex algo). What is the best way to do this with rails: gem and from scratch?

Comment: Is this title names are from a single model or multiple?

Comment: If you create this functionality from scratch you have the full control over your search.

Answer (score 0):

Use select2 jquery plugin. Its documentation is pretty cool as well. Visit https://select2.github.io/examples.html . Pass your collection to your form select box and call the class of it with select2. It will suggest the user according to the input.